# Distribution of minimum of normal variables

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Suppose $Z_0=min(X_1, X_2...X_N)$ and $Z_1=min(X_{N+1}, X_{N+2}...X_M)$ where $X_1 ... X_M$ are normally distributed variables with different means and variances and they are generally dependent (but they could be considered independent if there is no answer for the dependent case). Is there any way to compute $Pr(Z_0<Z_1)$?

Related to this question there are two other ones:  1) Based on which conditions $min(X1,X2)$ could be approximated as normal and what is its mean and variance? 2) Based on which conditions $min(X_1,X_2...X_N)=min(X_1,min(X_2...X_N))?$

if we know the answer of these two questions it seems that the first question is answerable since $Z_0$ and $Z_1$ could be approximated by normal distributions. Any assumption which leads to a clear answer is possible.

Comment: I really find this question too general. Assuming that $X_1,\ldots,X_M$ are independent you can always normalised them to have all same mean and variance and than distribution of minimum could be found for example [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/220/how-is-the-minimum-of-a-set-of-random-variables-distributed).

Comment: Maybe useful [The Minimum of n Independent Normal Distributions](http://www.untruth.org/~josh/math/normal-min.pdf)

Comment: Thank you for your comments the paper you mentioned is pretty useful but is there any condition to say min(X1,X2,X3)=min(X1,min(X2,X3))? @JKnecht